# Angular NgRx - How to view object from the store in my template html?

Tags: angular, ngrx

Hey i have object in store and i want to view the object in the template.

My Ts File:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { Store } from '@ngrx/store';
import { Comment } from '../../models/comment.model';
import { User } from '../../models/user.model';
import { AppState } from '../../app.state';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-ngrx-get-data',
  templateUrl: './ngrx-get-data.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./ngrx-get-data.component.scss']
})
export class NgrxGetDataComponent implements OnInit {
  comment$: Observable<Comment[]>;
  userDetails$: Observable<User>;

  constructor(private store: Store<AppState>) {
    this.comment$ = this.store.select('comment');
    this.userDetails$ = this.store.select('user');
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

My template:

```
<div style="margin: auto;">
<h1 style="text-align: center;">USER DETAILS FROM API</h1>
<li *ngFor="let item of userDetails$ | async ">
  <ul>{{item}}</ul>
</li>
</div>
```

My Error in console:

```
ERROR Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.
```

I try this and its not work:

```
<h1 style="text-align: center;">USER DETAILS FROM API</h1>
<li *ngFor="let item of userDetails$ | keyvalue">
  <ul>{{item.key}} {{item.value}}</ul>
</li>
```

Image if my state:
[image]

Comment: userDetails should be an array.

Comment: Can you show us what is your state looks like?

Comment: I edit the post with image of my state

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you need is to combine `async` and `keyvalue` pipes together. Also the order of the pipes important :

```
<h1 style="text-align: center;">USER DETAILS FROM API</h1>
<ul *ngFor="let item of userDetails$ | async | keyvalue">
  <li>{{item.key}}: {{item.value}}</li>
</ul>
```

Here's a demo stackblitz of this code: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-1rj8sc

Comment: Hey man its work but now i see in my browser the name of the field (the key) but i dont see the value

Comment: That's cause your NGRX has no value for userDetails, your screenshot shows everything to be null

Comment: Also thanks to @JamesD for fixing the syntax and adding stackblitz sample.

Comment: Yeah normally you'd dispatch a loadaction in the ngOnInit. Something like this.store.dispatch(UserCollectionActions.loadUser());

Answer (score 1):

This is the correct way to do it:

```html
<div style="margin: auto;">
    <h1 style="text-align: center;">USER DETAILS FROM API</h1>
    <ul *ngIf="userDetails$ | async as details">
        <li *ngFor="let item of details">{{item}}</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

First you need to let Angular subscribe to observable using async pipe, use that within an *ngIf otherwise it will try to iterate over something that does not exist yet. Next use *ngFor to create multiple `<li>` elements, not `<ul>`

Answer (score 0):

If your slice of state 'user' is normalized and stored as an object with the key: object structure, you'll need to convert that to an array to iterate over it in the template.

You can easily convert it to an array with something like this

```
  private userDetails: User;
  constructor(private store: Store<AppState>) {
    this.comment$ = this.store.select('comment');
    // Use Object.values() to convert to an array with all the values of that object
    this.userDetails$ = this.store.select('user').subscribe(userDetails => {
     this.userDetails = Object.values(userDetails);
    });
  }

  // Then

  <li *ngFor="let item of userDetails">
    <ul>{{item}}</ul>
  </li>
```

Though it's hard to know exactly what's going on without seeing the data structure.

Some other notes: If userDetails is just a single object, and you want to iterate over each property, and get the key and value, use [Object.entries()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries)

Comment: Type 'any[]' is missing the following properties from type 'Observable<User>': _isScalar, source, operator, lift, and 5 more.ts(2740)